# How to make each TextField of a BoxLayout.Y_AXIS have their own width?

Tags: java-me, containers, textfield, lwuit

There are `TextFields` , four , contained into a `Container` whose Layout is `BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)`. I want each of these `TextFields` to have their own width. I tried `setPreferredW` , also `setColumns` but the `TextFields` are all the same size which is occupying all the remaining row's width.

So how to make each or some `TextFields` have their own width visually ?

Comment: I can't understand your question. Can you tell me clearly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution : I derived the TextField class and in the constructor I set the preferred width value.

PS : I did not call `super();`

Answer (score 1):

BoxLayout always stretches components on the opposite AXIS so the text fields will always stretch regardless of their preferredW (another reason why you must never mess with that value unless you know what you are doing...).

The solution is simple, nest the text fields in multiple FlowLayout/BoxLayoutX containers and add the containers one by one to the box layout Y. The containers will each occupy the full width of the Y AXIS container but the text fields within won't take up all the space.

Comment: Container lines = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS); Container l = new Container(); l.addComponent(label); l.addComponent(tf); lines.addComponent(l);